# Can someone explain what each variable, operator, argument etc in this loops work?

Tags: javascript, loops

Just got into coding a week ago and I'm enjoying it for now. I realized I was going too fast through the curriculum on free code camp and will move onto the next section without fully understanding it. In this loop example, can someone explain to me how this loop fully works? The objective is to find the longest word in this sentence 'the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.'

-What does the var i stand for in this case?

-I played around with changing 'i = 0' and put numbers 1-9 and checked the result and got:
numbers 0-4 gives me "6"
numbers 5-7 gives me "4"
numbers 8 gives me "3"
and 9 gives me 0

I don't understand how those numbers resulted in 6,4,3, and 0. Can someone explain this to me. Thanks!

```
    function findLongestWordLength(str) {
      var words = str.split(' ');
      var maxLength = 0;

      for (var i = 9; i < words.length; i++) {
        if (words[i].length > maxLength) {
          maxLength = words[i].length;
        }
      }

      return maxLength;
    }
    console.log(findLongestWordLength("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog"));
```

Comment: I suggest reading how a for loop works first https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for

Comment: See also the javascript guide at  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide , It is a companion document to JavaScript Reference

Answer (score 2):

Indices start from #0 (the first word).  #1 is the second word, etc.  Word #8 of your sentence is "dog".

The `i = 9` means start checking at word #9.  (Which doesn't exist) and therefore results in the longest word has 0 letters.

If you start at word #5, you're only considering "over the lazy dog" and get the longest word has 4 letters.

If you start before that, you'll also consider "jumped" and you'll get the longest word has 6 letters.

---

Also:  off topic pet peeve (sorry!):  "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog" is a *pangram* (contains every letter of the alphabet).  But it is often misquoted as "jumped" instead of "jumps", which unfortunately makes it no longer a pangram because it needs the 's' from "jumps".  :(    So the answer should be 5.  ;)

Comment: Upped for the pangram info

Answer (score 1):

I have commented the code you posted with some explanations.

```js
// This defines a function that takes a parameter which will be referred to as str inside this function
function findLongestWordLength(str) {

  // this creates an array of strings by spliting the variable str on every space. Essentially this creates an array of the words in the input parameter
  var words = str.split(' '); 
  
  // this is the value we will return to the user. We initialise it to 0 before going through the list of words. It will be used to hold the length of the longest word.
  var maxLength = 0;

  // this loops through the array of words we created earlier. var i is the loop variable/counter
  // NOTE: this is setup wrong, var i should start from 0
  // basically we're saying perform the code inside the for loop until i is higher than the number of words we have then stop.
  // This is a traditional setup to loop through an array.
  for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
  
    // This if block is saying if the number of letters in the current word is more than the 
    // current maximum we have then it should be the new maximum
    if (words[i].length > maxLength) {
      maxLength = words[i].length;
    }
  }
  
  // finally we return to the caller the maximum we found
  return maxLength;
}
   
 console.log(findLongestWordLength("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog")); // 6 because jumped is the longest word
```

**A little more explanation on for loops:**

There are more than 1 way to loop through things. Loops are a way to perform the same code over and over again until a certain criteria is met.

Because we have a list of words and we know how many words we have a **for** loop is suitable to go through them.

A for loop setup in the way you have your code uses a counter.

1. First you set the initial value of the counter (0)
2. then you tell the loop the condition it needs to meet to stop looping, in this case when the counter reaches the number of words we have.
3. Finally, you specify a little bit of code to execute at the end of each iteration, in this case i++. `i++` is essentially the same as `i = i + 1` which increments the counter after each iteration. Without it we will never meet the criteria we set and the loop will execute forever.

I hope that helps.

Comment: The OP's code had `var i = 9`, although they did try various values there.

Comment: Yeah I noticed. The initial value of i determines from which word in the sentence they start "looking" at. When it's 9 it basically means looking at the word after "dog" which isn't there and that's why they were getting 0 as the length of the longest word.